# pickle error when called in class

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to put a method in one of my classes which will allow me to pickle and unpickle files.  So for example, I have

```
import pickle

class SomeClass:

    def otherMethods:
        pass

    def save_to_file(self, filename, file_to_save):
        with (filename,'wb') as output:
            pickle.dump(file_to_save,output,pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        print("Data has been saved.")
```

Now, when I create an instance of this 'SomeClass', I expect to be able to call as follows from the terminal...

```
myfile = [1,2,3] # or anything else
SomeClass.save_to_file('myfile.pk',myfile)
```

However, what gets thrown is an:

```
'AttributeError: __exit__'
```

I've seen a few different posts of people having difficulties with similar use cases, but I haven't been able to figure out how they apply in my situation.  Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you call `SomeClass.save_to_file` or `SomeClassObj.save_to_file`?

Comment: I created an instance of SomeClass... i.e a = SomeClass(), then a.save_to_file(...)

Comment: maybe simplify the 'with' statement

Comment: @donfede how can I simplify the 'with' statement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`open` is missing:

```
with open(filename,'wb') as output:
```

The with statement expects a context manager with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, and raises `AttributeError` because the tuple `(filename,'wb')` does not have them.